# Flutter: How can I set a background image for Circle Avatar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have an image in my assets folder and want to set as background for circle Avatar how should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CircleAvatar(
  backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/image.png'),
);
```

This will work for you.

Make sure you have added an image in the asset folder and path inside pubspec.yaml file

like

```
assets:
    - assets/image.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have the Image in your `Assets` folder.

1) Add it to your `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
assets:
    - assets/yourimage.png
```

2) Specify the image as the `backgroundImage` of your `CircleAvatar`:

```
CircleAvatar(
  // the circle avatar has the background image property for specifying images
  backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/yourimage.png'),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
CircleAvatar(
              child: Image.network(
        "https://miro.medium.com/proxy/1*ilC2Aqp5sZd1wi0CopD1Hw.png",
        fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
      ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will give you a avatar with a background that will show while loading a network image

```dart
CircleAvatar(
   backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
   backgroundImage: AssetImage('/path/to/asset.png'),
   child: Image.network('https://www.example.com/with/online.png')
);
```

Don't forget to put the path to the asset folder in your pubspec.yml